# Why deallocation function is not called when object constructor throw in a new expression?

Tags: c++, new-operator, dynamic-memory-allocation, delete-operator

If I define operator delete as following and if an object constructor throw in the new expression I expected to see the result of the call to the defined operator delete:

```
#include <new>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

void*
operator new(std::size_t s){
  std::cout << "alloc " << std::endl;
return std::malloc(s);
}

void
operator delete(void* p) noexcept {
  std::cout << "dealloc " << std::endl;
  std::free(p);
}
void
operator delete(void* p,std::size_t) noexcept{
    std::free(p);
    std::cout << "dealloc s" << std::endl;
}

struct A{
  A(int i){
     if(i>0)
       throw 10;
  }
};

int main(int argc// will equal 10
        ,char* arg[])
{
  for(int i=0;i<argc;++i)
     auto p=new A{argc};
  return 0;
}
```

This program just output `alloc`, why the operator delete are not called? In the standard [expr.new] it is specified that:

> If any part of the object initialization described above terminates by throwing an exception and a suitable
>   deallocation function can be found, the deallocation function is called to free the memory in which the object
>   was being constructed, after which the exception continues to propagate in the context of the new-expression.

Comment: You don't have try catch block.

Comment: @Jarod42 You are right!Thank you! I need catch block because living the main function with an exception is UB or is it for some other prior reason?

Comment: It is for the UB part. BTW, `return i;` is invalid (`i` is out of scope).

Comment: @Jarod42: it's not UB. When an exception isn't caught std::terminate is called.

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks. I remove the i, it was not intentional.

Comment: Note that operator << has no noexcept specification so technically your version of delete can throw

Comment: Which is the value of `argc` ? I suppose 1, so you don't throw exception.

Comment: No actualy is larger than 1!! Otherwise I would not have ask the question. I checked with clang and gcc. I make it equal to zero in order to not create to much distraction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you fix your code to throw exception, it works as expected:

```
int main(int argc,char* arg[])
{
    try {
        new A(2);
    }
    catch (...)
    {}
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/09ae44f3e0ff688d)

Answer (score 2):

As others already noted, it is because you do not catch the exception. As the standard notes:

> **C++11 §15.3/9**:
>   “If no matching handler is found, the function `std::terminate()`  is called; whether or not the stack is unwound before this call to `std::terminate()` is implementation-defined.”

While I think this is not specifically related to the stack in your case, the same principle will hold here, too. So it is actually up to the implementation if any memory is cleaned up. As we see here, it is usually not the case, because the operating system cleans up the memory anyway.

Comment: I am interested by your post because you answer to the "why?". I don't think the memory clean-up is involved here. Implementations must ensure that visible side effects actually happens (memory clean-up may not be considered a side effect). I/O is a visible side effect. So Clang and GCC have probably implemented the memory deallocation as part of the stack unwinding process, nothing in the standard forbid this, and in GCC documentation, it is specified that terminate does not perform stack unwinding. Thanks I understand now!

Answer (score 1):

If during construction using `new`, a constructor throws an exception, the C++ runtime library:

1. calls `std::terminate()` if no suitable catch handler is found. Whether or not `delete` is called is implementation defined.

or

2. calls `delete` for you before "sending" that exception to the suitable catch handler if one is found, although the destructor is not called - i.e. `~A()`, if you had one, would not be called when `i` is greater than 1.

Comment: I do not think that applies here: If you catch the exception, the defined delete operator IS called, while it is not called if there is no catch. So your "before giving you that exception" is very ambiguous.

Comment: @koalo Yes I've made a right pigs ear of this answer. I've amended.